# Why does calling grecaptcha.render() multiple times load Google's ReCAPTCHA library multiple times?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recaptcha, deferred

I'm facing an issue where calling grecaptcha.render() more than once on the same page seems to reload Google's ReCAPTCHA library multiple times. I have two different forms on a single page and each form has its own ReCAPTCHA. However, each grecaptcha.render() call seems to initiate a new library download. Is this expected behavior, and if not, how can I resolve it?

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmR7fIi6khfIWMHt1B4eg8KqyOnO66Vxs&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=marker,places"
    defer
></script>

<script>
    function onRecaptchaLoadCallback() {
        console.log("ReCAPTCHA loaded successfully.");
        console.log(grecaptcha)
        myfunc()
    }

    function recaptchaErrorCallback() {
        console.log("An error occurred while loading ReCAPTCHA.");
    }

    function myfunc() {
        if (typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined') { // Проверка, что ReCaptcha API загрузилась
            console.log(grecaptcha)

            if (document.getElementById('modal-captcha') !== null) {
                modalCaptcha = grecaptcha.render('modal-captcha', {
                    'sitekey': '{{ env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY') }}'
                });
            }

            if (document.getElementById('bottom-captcha') !== null) {
                bottomCaptcha = grecaptcha.render('bottom-captcha', {
                    'sitekey': '{{ env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY') }}'
                });
            }
        }
```

I've tried initializing ReCAPTCHA using Google's recommended async and defer attributes on the  tag and an onload callback to ensure the library is ready. I was expecting the library to load once and then allow multiple grecaptcha.render() calls for different elements without re-downloading the library. But what's happening is that for each render call, the library gets downloaded again.